# How do I display a message to users who pick certain shipping zip codes

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, shipping, zipcode

I need to display something like a warning message or something like that when a user selects certain shipping zip codes. I would be ok with an extension of some sort. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: How user will select certain zip codes?

Comment: Sorry I meant country. They would pick the country from dropdown at checkout.